# Android UI examples

Tags: android

I am new with Android UI and I am looking for some resources about best practices to design a UI (examples of UI elements, tutorials, etc.)

I've been looking in Google or http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials but there is nothing helpful at all.

Can anyone provide me some resources/links ?

Comment: Not really _resources about best practices_, but a collection of apps that you can browse through: http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/

Comment: @Jim Schubert - Where do I go to download or view code on any of those apps.  The page you linked does not provide a link to a download and searching turns up zilch.

Comment: check out some nice tutorials in below link for android UI http://javatechig.com/tutorials/android/

Comment: If you are using Jetpack Compose, check out https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uidesigns.withsourcecode . I have added many UI designs along with source code and the app is free.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is actually a nice web which explains the most usable UI Design patters used by many apps already: http://www.androidpatterns.com/

Answer (score 8):

If you have no experience with Android UI but you know a little Java already, maybe [this](https://github.com/bitstars/SimpleUi) is something for you:

[SimpleUi ( https://github.com/bitstars/SimpleUi )](https://github.com/bitstars/SimpleUi)

The generated UI (code below):

[image]

[The complete code to create this Android UI](https://github.com/bitstars/SimpleUi/blob/master/SimpleUiExamples/src/de/rwth/StartExampleUi.java):

[image]

I use it in real applications, not only for fast prototyping or dialogs and its well tested over the years. The concept is based on the model view control principle and for most common scenarios there are ready to use components which automatically look correct on any device. I don't say it should be used for any UI (e.g. listviews should be done by hand) but for most usecases this should be quite handy ;) Oh and feel free to fork it and improve it further if you want

Answer (score 6):

UI Patterns, shown on the Twitter app, but they're common on Android in general:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/twitter-for-android-closer-look-at.html

http://www.androiduipatterns.com/

Depending which pattern you want to implement, there are open source projects/samples out there, i.e. for the Quick Contact Bar, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Check [anddev](http://www.anddev.org/).. normally there are nice examples of UI elements. Also some nice tutorials at mobiforge [1](http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-1-layouts) and [2](http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-2-views).